# Why does adding two values in nVelocity always returns zero?

Tags: nvelocity

I'm trying to add two values in velocity and it always returns 0.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#set ($tmpPrice = $orderItem.ExtendedPrice + $discountAmount)
```

Both $orderItem.ExtendedPrice & $discountAmount are whole numbers with decimals, like this: 99.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
#set ($tmpPrice = $orderItem.ExtendedPrice.ToDecimal(null) + $discountAmount.ToDecimal(null))
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

try `$tmpPrice = ($orderItem.ExtendedPrice + $discountAmount)`